# C: scanf doesn't work as I want

Tags: c, scanf

I want that the program controls the user's input (must be a char/letter), but if I put "xx" it goes out of the loop, why?

```
        char c;
        int i = 0;
        do{
            if(i!=0){
                printf("Wrong!\n");
            }
            printf("Insert char: ");
            scanf(" %c", &c);
            i++;
        }while(c<'a' && c>'z' && c<'A' && c>'Z');
```

-----> Edit/correct

This piece of code should read a single character from the keyboard (must be a letter, it does not matter whether it is lowercase or uppercase), if it were not so I write "wrong".

As you told me I corrected the condition of the do/while, now the code is:

```
            do{
                if(i!=0){
                    printf("Wrong!\n");
                }
                printf("Insert char: ");
                scanf(" %c", &c);
                i++;
            }while(!((c>='a' && c<='z') || (c>='A' && c<='Z')));
```

**Input examples:**

What I expect

- 'a' -> exit to the loop
- 'aa' -> remain in the loop
- '.' -> remain in the loop
- '..' -> remain in the loop

What happens

- 'a' -> exit to the loop
- 'aa' -> exit to the loop
- '.' -> remain in the loop
- '..' -> remain in the loop (but it print me two time "wrong")

If I do not put the space in the scanf, so ("%c"), the program prints me automatically "wrong" and "insert char" (it just makes a loop)

(p.s. I apologize if I had not explained very well the problem before)

Comment: Think how can `c` be both `>'z'` and `<'a'`... It's really not (only) about `scanf`..

Comment: Check the return value of `scanf`

Comment: The only character values guaranteed to be represented as contiguous binary values are the digits `0` - `9`.  There is no guarantee that `a`-`z` and `A`-`Z` are represented consecutively.  Per the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **5.2.1 Character sets**

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes, but practically ASCII is used about everywhere (tell where it isn't) and there a-z and A-Z are contiguous.

Comment: Another one bites the dust... (compound boolean expression with no intermediate temp vars to make debugging easy).

Comment: "As you told me I corrected the condition of the do/while, now the code is: ..."  is not good SO etiquette as it significantly  changes the question.  Good to add detail but a post that is a moving target is not well received.  Suggest changing code back.

Answer (score 3):

Your condition for

```
while(c<'a' && c>'z' && c<'A' && c>'Z');
```

will never be true.

> but if I put "xx" it goes out of the loop, why?

Since do-while is an exit-condition loop, the only time you enter the loop is the first time.

Comment: *`" %c"` requires a space and then a character.* Not true. It simply means that skip whitespaces if there are any. See http://ideone.com/Q2xVyj.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.21.6.2 The fscanf function 5 A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails.*

Comment: @RSahu : My mistake. Edited this.

Comment: @EOF : Appreciate the time.

Comment: @sjsam: I've gotten pretty good at looking up the easy stuff in the standard. Takes less than a minute if you know where to look.

Comment: @EOF : I have too started this recently. Getting good is just a matter of time i believe :D

Answer (score 1):

The specifier `%c` indicates a [character](/questions/tagged/character). Accordingly, your `while` loop checks for single characters but you give as an input a [string](/questions/tagged/string).

If you want to input a `string`, change your `scanf` statement to :

```
scanf("%s", &s);
```

as the specifier `%c` indicates a `string`. You will need to modify your `while` loop accordingly in order for your condition to become `true` at some point.

Comment: *requires to read a space followed by a character.* Not true. See my comment to the answer by @sjsam.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(c<'a' && c>'z' && c<'A' && c>'Z')
```

is always false, that's why.

If it were true:

```
if(i!=0){ printf("Wrong!\n");}
```

will always print false(except the first time).

I don't know exactly what you want.

Comment: *"I dont know exactly what you want"* So this should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the condition, it's always false.

Example code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>

int main ()
{
    char c;
    do scanf("%c", &c);
    while(tolower(c)<'a' || tolower(c)>'z');
    printf("%c\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use `<ctype.h>`, why not just `isalpha(c)`?

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &c);` and `scanf("%c", &c);` are not the same. The first one will skip leading whitespace while the second will not.